# How can I build android apps using python on Windows

Tags: android, python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

I would like to build Android Apps in python using preferably the QT framework, if I have to do away with it, when it comes to android fine, but the development process has to be on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use python to develop android apps below is the link which will guide you to develop Android app using `Python`.
https://hameedullah.com/develop-your-first-android-application-in-python.html

Comment: Not what I was looking for. Thanks anyway.